# Memoized class variable returning inconsistent values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, airtable

I'm really sorry in advance if this question is going to look messy; I'll do my best to make it concise.

I am building a class that emulates an ActiveRecord model, but gets its data from a service called [Airtable](https://airtable.com/), not a database. Airtable is like a cross between Excel and a database - it lets you create a spreadsheet of data but supports "foreign keys" between different tables so you can link data between tables. This works out really nicely for an application I'm working on.

In order to make it extensible and flexible, I created a parent class, `AirtableModel`, which defines common methods and attributes that will be filled out when classes inherit from it. The inheriting class's name will help the parent methods access the data from the correct Airtable table and retrieve the correct attributes. The relevant bits are below (ones that aren't mentioned are self-explanatory or are inconsequential to the problem):

```
class AirtableModel
  def initialize(hash)
    hash.each do |attribute_name, attribute_value|
      attribute_value = self.class.first_value_from_arrays_with_singular_key_name(attribute_name, attribute_value)
      # ^^^ Airtable always returns references as Arrays. If the relationship is a belongs_to, we pull out the value from the Array.

      begin
        attribute_name_as_class = attribute_name.to_s.singularize.camelize.constantize
        # ^^^ Converts the attribute's name to a class constant. Used to make the generated method retrieve class records instead of ids. If the class doesn't exist, its NameError is caught below.
        instance_variable_set("@#{attribute_name}_airtable_ids", attribute_value)

        self.class.send(:define_method, attribute_name.to_sym) do
          result = attribute_name_as_class.find_all_by_airtable_id(instance_variable_get("@#{attribute_name}_airtable_ids"))
          result.length <= 1 ? result.first : result
        end
      rescue NameError
        # Triggered if `attribute_name_as_class` doesn't match an existing class
        instance_variable_set("@#{attribute_name}", attribute_value)
        self.class.send(:define_method, attribute_name.to_sym) do
          instance_variable_get("@#{attribute_name}")
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # Reaches out to Airtable to get all records for this class's table (the Airtable table matches the class name). Collects the resulting data into an array of Hashes.
  # One such hash might look like this:
  #   {
  #     'id' => <unique string ID assigned by Airtable>,
  #     'fields' => {
  #       'db_id' => <Unique integer ID. I added this to emulate a database record>,
  #       ...
  #     }
  #   }
  def self.airtable
    @airtable_records ||= AirtableService.records_from_table(table_name: "#{self}s").each.map do |raw|
      object_properties = raw['fields']
      object_properties['airtable_id'] = raw['id']
      object_properties['id'] = object_properties['db_id']

      Hash[object_properties.collect { |k, v| [k.snakecase.parameterize.underscore.to_sym, v] }]
      # ^^^ Converts parameter name to snake-case symbol, i.e. :db_id
    end
  end

  def self.all
    @all_records ||= airtable.map { |b| new(b) }
  end

  def self.find_by_airtable_id(airtable_id)
    objects = all.select { |b| b.airtable_id == airtable_id }
    raise "non unique airtable_id found" if objects.size > 1
    objects.first
  end

  def self.find_all_by_airtable_id(airtable_ids)
    [airtable_ids].flatten.map { |aid| find_by_airtable_id(aid) }
    # ^^^ Accomodates airtable_ids as an Array or a single value
  end

  def self.first
    all.first
  end

  def self.last
    all.last
  end
end
```

If anything above doesn't make sense, let me know and I'll be happy to update.

This has worked perfectly for the majority of my classes that inherit from `AirtableModel`, but I'm having an issue with a particular table (FooBar) which is supposed to act like a join table between two other tables. That would look something like this:

```
[Table Foo]                   [Table FooBar]                  [Table Bar]
fooBars <==========---------> foo     bar <---------========> fooBars
```

Their class definitions are very simple:

```
class Foo < AirtableModel
end

class FooBar < AirtableModel
end

class Bar < AirtableModel
end
```

Thanks to the constructors above, I can make a call like `Foo.first.foo_bars` and get back an Array of all `FooBar` instances related to this `Foo`. This works without issue in the console, but I am running into an issue trying the above snippet in my Rails application.

`foo_bars` gets called twice in a single controller create action. This happens to call `self.all` twice. The first time, I get the expected result back - `@all_records` equals the number of records I have in Airtable, with the proper attribute values, including foreign key relationships. However, the second time the method is entered, the value of `@all_records` changes to an empty Array. The object that invokes `foo_bars` hasn't changed, and still includes the correct `airtable_ids` which are used to look up the associated `FooBar` instances. `@airtable_records` - the return value from the `self.airtable` method - still has the same values too.

I'm not sure what's causing the memoized `@all_records` variable to change value. I've been banging my head against it, using a debugger to follow the function calls step by step, but I can't see what's causing the value to change. Can anyone provide any advice on how to debug this further? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: I confess I didn't read your question thoroughly (it's a bit long-winded), but one thing jumps out as a bit unconventional - you are memoizing an instance variable in a class method.  Though you can do this in ruby, because classes are also objects, that's typically not the intent.  Instead, I wonder if you intend to be using a class variable, e.g. `@@airtable_records`.  Note the `@@` for class variables as opposed to `@` for instance variables.

Comment: @SeanHuber instance variables of `Class` instances (custom classes are all the instances of `Class` class) is a perfectly valid pattern. Furthermore, using `@@` class variables in ruby is discouraged due to their weird behaviour on derived classes.

Comment: Fair enough, I take back my comment.  A memoized class level variable does still seem like code smell to me.  If the goal is to have a single object holding some information, I'd think you'd want to go with a singleton approach.

Comment: @SeanHuber Singleton. Why didn't I think of that? That's a great idea. I'll give it a shot and update here. Thank you!

Comment: @SeanHuber also, yeah, sorry for the long-winded question. There's a lot of depth to this implementation. I actually tried class variables using `@@`, but it produced..weird results.

Comment: @SeanHuber The Singleton module didn't seem to solve this problem. Like I mentioned, I put a breakpoint on the only place in my code that would change the value of `@all_records`. After the first hit, it goes from `nil` to a fully-populated `Array`. Somehow, on the second hit, it has then gone from that fully-populated `Array` to an empty one, not nil. I have no idea what's causing this to happen. This is also happening in one controller action call, so the values should still be present in memory.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the answer is really stupid.

`all` is returning an Array of objects. Elsewhere in the class, we have this method:

```
def self.where(filter = {})
    filtered_objects = all

    filter.each do |filter_property, filter_value|
      # filter_value = filter_value.airtable_id if filter_value.respond_to?(:airtable_id)
      filtered_objects.select! do |object|
        object_value = object.send(filter_property)

        match_check = lambda do |value|
          if object_value.is_a?(Array)
            object_value.include?(value)
          else
            object_value == value
          end
        end

        filter_value.is_a?(Array) ? filter_value.any? { |v| match_check.call(v) } : match_check.call(filter_value)
      end
    end

    filtered_objects
  end
```

If `filtered_objects` == `all`, and we call `select!` on `filtered_objects`, what would happen?

Yup. It modified the object references directly. Making `all` return a `.dup`'d version of the Array solves the problem.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Comment: Thanks @SeanHuber! Hopefully this helps someone else out.